# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir en forma de triángulo usando números primos?

Tags: python, funciones, números-primos

He estado intentando hacer un prigrama que imprima un triángulo usando solo números primos.

Para generar los números primos, u´se la criba de Eratostenes hasta cierto número.

La idea es que esos números se guardarían en una lista la cual sería convertida a `str` para que en una variable, se guardaran progresivamente asi tener un triangulo como el siguiente:

2

3 2

5 3 2

7 5 3 2

Esto es lo que he intentando:

```
def Criba_Eratostenes(n):
  primos = []
  no_primos = []
  for i in range(2, n+1):
    if i not in no_primos:
      primos.append(i)
      
      for j in range(i*i, n + 1, i):
        no_primos.append(j)
  return primos
lista = str(Criba_Eratostenes(600))
impresiones = ""
for i in range(4):
  
  impresiones = lista[i]+ impresiones
  print(impresiones)
```

Pero obtengo esto:

```
[
2[
,2[
 ,2[
```

Comment: para que la lista de `no_primos` si al final no la retornas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mayor problema de tu código es que conviertes la lista en string antes de tiempo. Cuando tu utilizas el método `str()` la cadena resultante tiene la forma `[0, 1, 2]`, entonces cuando accedes a la posición 0 el valor es `"["`. En el siguiente código te muestro como lo haría yo, tomando primero los números primos que requiero, convertirlos en string, y reemplazar los caracteres no deseados.

```
def criba_eratostenes(n):
  primos = []
  no_primos = []
  for i in range(2, n+1):
    if i not in no_primos:
      primos.append(i)
      
      for j in range(i*i, n + 1, i):
        no_primos.append(j)
  return primos

lista = criba_eratostenes(600)
impresiones = ""
for i in range(5):
  fila = str([lista[x] for x in range(i, -1, -1)])
  fila = fila.replace(',', '')
  fila = fila.replace('[', '')
  fila = fila.replace(']', '')
  impresiones += fila + '\n'

print(impresiones)
```

Comment: Hola @ElAlien725, me podrías explicar la notación del range(i, -1, -1)? ¿Qué significa acada digito dentro del parentesis?

Comment: @Siderius'Nuncius eso es para invertir un iterable

Comment: Eso lo se hace con el fin de convertir toda la lista a str? Es que no me queda muy claro.

Comment: @Siderius'Nuncius La lista de los primos es [2, 3, 5, 7 ...], entonces yo lo que hago es tomar los primeros i valores, pero al hacer range(i, -1, -1) lo recorro de manera invertida. Para que te quede claro sería range( valorInicial, valorFinal, incremento), aclaro que valorFinal es no incluyente, si pones -1 llegará hasta 0. Lo que hay ahí se llama comprensión de lista, te recomiendo que leas sobre eso ya que es una característica interesante de python. https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/list-comprehensions-in-python--cms-26836

Comment: @Siderius'Nuncius La lista resultante la convierto en string. Cuando i vale 0, el resultado es "[2]", cuando vale 1 es "[3, 2]", cuando vale 2 es "[5, 3, 2]" y así sucesivamente. Luego elimino los paréntesis rectos y las comas. Por último sumo la fila a la variable impresiones es inserto un salto de linea con "\n".

Answer (score 2):

Esto siempre es interesante, tu problema se resuelve simplemente reemplazando a `lista = criba_eratostenes(600)` y colocando `impresiones = str(lista[i])+ impresiones`, no hace falta hacer ningún `replace()`. Pero te digo que tu código se puede optimizar mucho.

El algoritmo nos dice que debemos de parar cuando el numero actual (`i`) elevado al cuadro (`i^2`) supera al numero natural de primos (`n`) que deseamos encontrar, lo que vendría a ser la raíz cuadrada del numero de primos a encontrar (`n^0.5`). por lo que podemos minimizar las iteraciones. También podemos usar una comprensión de lista para obtener los múltiplos del numero actual (`i`), ósea, cuando `x%i == 0`

```py
def Criba_Eratostenes(n):
  no_primos = []
  data = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]

  for i in range(2, int(n+1*0.5)):
    if i**2 > n: break #esta de mas
    #obtenemos los no primos del numero
    no_primos += [x for x in data if x%i==0 and x!=i] 

  # obtenemos los primos, hallando la diferencia
  primos = set(data)-set(no_primos)
  #podemos retornar ambos: return list(primos),no_primos
  return list(primos)
```

Con `set()` borramos los elementos repetidos, esto nos ayuda ha poder hacer operaciones de conjuntos, como la *diferencia*.

Ahora para imprimirlos basta con la notación de *slice* (`[inicio:fin:paso]`) con esto podemos coger unos determinados elementos de la lista

```
lista1 = Criba_Eratostenes(100) #obtenemos los 100 primeros

for i in range(1,5): #imprimimos los 4 primeros
    #convetimos cada elemento de la lista a string y los unimos con join
    impresiones = str(" ".join(str(x) for x in lista1[1:i]))
    print(impresiones)
```

**resultado**

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 5
```

Esto se puede optimizar aun más pero te lo dejo a ti, si tienes dudas no dudes en preguntarme :D.

Comment: se me olvido decir que el `break` estaba de más

Comment: Pero usando tu función se obtienen números como 4, 6 , 8. Esos son no primos.

Comment: @ElAlien725 gracias, me confundí, hallé los no primos :/

Comment: @ElAlien725 listo, la respuesta fue editada :D